# Continuous Scanner input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing sort of main practice project, where I can just continually add classes that do completely different fun things. For example, I have a CoinFlipperCmd and a poker PotOddsCmd, and the code currently works fine, but I want to be able to repeatedly enter commands without having to rerun the program. Example console currently:

```
FLIP 10 // coinflips 10 times and notes the outcome
You flipped 5 heads and 5 tails
```

After this, the code will exit, but I want to be able to keep entering commands. Like so:

```
FLIP 5
You flipped 4 heads and 1 tails
FLIP 6
You flipped 3 heads and 3 tails
POTODDS 0.5 1
You have pot odds of 2:1
```

I'm using a scanner for input

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputScanner();
    }

    private static void InputScanner() {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter command");

        String command = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
        ParseAndDirect(command);
    }

    private static void ParseAndDirect(String command) {
        String[] commandSplit = command.split(" ", 2);
        String usercommand = commandSplit[0];

        if (usercommand.equals("FLIP")){
            CoinFlipperCmd.CoinFlipperCmd(commandSplit[1]);
        } else if (usercommand.equals("POTODDS")){
            PotOddsCmd.PotOddsCmd(commandSplit[1]);
        } else System.out.println("Invalid Command");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you've nowhere used a for loop. You may use the infinite `for` loop or a `while` loop which will keep asking user after each execution if they wants still to play. But according to you question wanted results, you should use `for (; ;)` to keep going infinitely.

Comment: Where is `main` in your code? the `InputScanner` constructor kinda looks as if you wanted it to be a `main` but I don't know.

Comment: Anyway, having all the logic in constructors is really weird. Those should be regular methods most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the input part inside a loop e.g.

```
private static void InputScanner() {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
    String command;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter command (q to quit): ");
        command = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input
        if (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            ParseAndDirect(command);
        }
    } while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
}
```

Another way of using the loop can be as follows:

```
private static void InputScanner() {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
    String command;
    while(true)
        System.out.print("Enter command (q to quit): ");
        command = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            break;
        }
        ParseAndDirect(command);
    } 
}
```

**On a side note** (because it won't have any impact on the execution of the program), you should always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g the method, `ParseAndDirect` should be named as `parseAndDirect` and `InputScanner` should be named as `inputScanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from allowing the user to repeatedly enter commands, I think you should also allow some way to quit the program (besides having to kill it via the operating system :-) In the below code, I have arbitrarily used the word *quit* as the way to exit the loop. Feel free to use a different string.

```java
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = "";
while (!"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    System.out.println("Enter command");
    if (!"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
        ParseAndDirect(command);
    }
}
```

By the way, according to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) the method name should be `parseAndDirect`, i.e. it should start with a lowercase letter.